# can i use vClick and usefastclick with jQuery mobile version 1.3.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i read about `vclick` and `click`. `vclick` is faster then click in jQuery Mobile. So i will want to  use `vclick` but i am confuse that vclick is worked or not in `jQuery mobile 1.3.0` ?

I also want to know that what is `$.mobile.useFastClick = false;`? is this work in `jQuery mobile 1.3.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `jQuery mobile 1.3.0` do supports `vclick`. You can check the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) yourself. Another [question](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/faq/how-do-i-use-touch-mouse-events.php) from official Q&A

I ran a fiddle with `$.mobile.useFastClick = false` and it works fine. So we can assume `$.mobile.useFastClick = false` do works in `jQuery mobile 1.3.0`

Find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Q8f7E/

Comment: So vclick is faster then simple click ?

Comment: yes it is. I hope you read the link I've given above. It elaborateness why `vclick` is faster than normal `click`.

Comment: Can you give your mail id or chat id for future refrence?

Comment: Check my profile and connect to me via Twitter or Linkedin. I dont think rules here would allow me to share contacts. Sorry.

Comment: Just FYI: jQuery Mobile doesn't have useFastClick as a flag anymore: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/. The reason that flag "worked" is because you just added a field to that object, it doesn't actually do anything :)